# What do I have to do to set up Google Cloud SQL with App Maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

In Tutorial 2: Work with Data. 
https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/work-with-data
I have a problem. Create a model. I can't choose Google Cloud SQL.

What do I have to do to choose Google Cloud SQL?

[image: Create model]

Comment: I think the answer you are looking for is right here https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

As Mofrinismo said look on https://support.google.com/a/answer/7550053?hl=en but make sure to follow the last step "Edit Cloud SQL roles" make sure to add the appmaker-maestro service account and provide the correct roles, this should fix it.